# Импорт данных из БД Access в Excel на C#

Tags: c#, база-данных, excel

У меня на `winForm` есть `datagridview` с подключением к БД Access, и нужно в .xls файл передать данные из этой базы данных.

В БД Access 4 таблицы, есть `comboBox` c названиями этих таблиц, и при выборе определенной таблицы по нажатию кнопки данные из этой таблицы импортируются в Excel.

Допустим, я вычитала в dataset данные из таблицы, а как потом записать их в Excel?

Comment: Можно экспортировать в совместимый с Excel формат CSV (библиотека CsvHelper) или использовать библиотеку ClosedXML для работы с XLSX, ещё можно использовать сам Excel через Interop. А вообще Access вроде сам умеет экспортировать данные в этих форматах.